# Removing or skipping items in list

Tags: python, list, replace, sum

I have a CSV file and need to remove or just skip or replace with `0` some missing data that is represented as `None` in the list. `Row1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, none, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and `row2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, none, 7, 8, 9]` in the CSV file.

```
counter=0

for lines in csv:

    list_all=lines.split(',')
    list_all=lines.strip()
    counter+=1
    for ch in range(len(list_all)):
        if list_all[ch]=='?':
            list_all.replace('?',0)
    list_0=float(list_all[0])
    list0.append(list_0)
    avelist0=(sum(list0)/counter)
```

I need to get the sum of all the values from each column; not including the `None`, of course. I keep getting an error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly.
```

I'm still new to Python and I would like to do this with a `for` loop if possible. I can't use list comprehensions.

So the average of first list would be `22.5` and `22.5` for the second list.

Comment: You need to replace the `'?'` with the string `'0'`, not the number `0`.

Comment: Note that you will get different averages for skipping the `None`s vs. replacing them with zero...

Comment: The problem is that only replaces the first one and not all of them

Comment: `replace()` replaces all instances, not just the first.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't use list comprehensions, what you want to do is `map` over the list:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,None,5,6,7,8,9] 
new_l = map(lambda x: 0 if x.lower().strip() == 'none' else int(x), l)
print new_l #  [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Then if you want sum the entire list, use `sum`:

```
sum(new_l) #  returns 45
```

Comment: I couldn't use lamba because I have to add each column of the csv together. Map would be nice but I haven't used that in class yet so I can't use it.

Comment: The issue is that CSV files are read in as strings, so they need additional processing before a solution like this would work.

Comment: @DavidJorgenson - the `map` is only an intermediary step to make all values numeric. You can then simply run it through the `sum` function. Take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - you are correct - updated answer to ensure we are working with `int`s